# What is Dell's "Permanent" VLAN?

Tags: vlan, dell

I am aware of the following types of Vlan's.

```
Default VLAN: This is basically where ALL ports belongs to by default, this is technically VLAN 1 and it can't be deleted from the switch. 

Data VLAN: 

Native VLAN: The native VLAN is an 802.1Q only concept. 

Voice VLAN: The voice VLAN is where the QoS policies are applied in order to prioritize this traffic to send it through the LAN. 

Management VLAN: This is used on a LAN for management purporses. 

Special VLANs: These VLANs are basically used for special cases on your LAN. 

Reserved VLANs: There are some VLANs that are reserved internally on your switch in order to use them on other enviroments like FDDI, Token Ring.

Private VLANs it's a technology that has some new concpets/category of VLANs.
```

But recently in a dell powerconnect switch i saw Vlan type as ***permanent***. Can anybody please tell me what a permanent vlan type would mean.

Comment: These are just made up names for vlans. None of them mean anything.

Comment: Standard only mentions 0, 1 and 4095 specifically. 0 meaning no vlan tagging, only cos information. 1 is mentioned as default for classifying frames on ingress and 4095 is reserved and should not be used.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Dell-speak," a permanent vlan means that the setting is saved to a file so that the VLAN is configured when the switch is booted up.  Otherwise rebooting the switch would delete the vlan configuration.

It's roughly the same as "copy run start" on a Cisco switch.

And I agree with John -- the VLAN "types" are arbitrary and vendor-specific.

Comment: Is it possible to add a CLI capture that illustrates how PowerConnects refer to "permanent" Vlans?

Answer (score 2):

I found this information on a Dell support forum: *If a packet arrives at the port from an end device carrying no VLAN tag, then the switch will add a VLAN tage which corresponds to the PVID, and then forward it within that VLAN; so the PVID mechanisim allows you to have traffic originating from a non-VLAN aware device to become an 802.1q packet, so that it can traverse to other switches and still be contained within the correct VLAN; so PVID is for non tagged packets arriving at a port on the switch.*.
I found this at: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/866/t/18619540.aspx .

So it appears to be a Dell proprietary item, which would partially explain its unfamiliarity to many of us. If you are tasked with maintaining or configuring this switch, I believe your best course is going to require becoming intimately familiar with the Dell way of thinking.

Comment: Note: the "P" in "PVID" stand for primary, not permanent. PVID is a well-known term across vendors.

Answer (score -1):

All of these terms arbitrary. A Vlan is a Vlan, some perform special functions though.

I.E.

Private VLAN configuration
RSPAN VLAN configuration